# Getting "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression" in C# trying to INSERT INTO .accdb

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2010

So I have the below code, and upon clicking "button3", is supposed to insert the contents of my dataGridView into my database. I am getting the error:

**"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '   '** , with the first value of my first column in the single quotes, as if it read the data, but can't tell what to do with it. When I click the "OK" to dismiss the message, and another message pops up and the second value of that same column now in single quotes; and so on, until the last value is reached, and then finally, an error box pops up with:

**"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"**

I plan to parameterize the code after I get it working; so no worries about that.  :-)

**Please help!!!! All help is appreciated.**

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            string ConnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Search\\Database.accdb"; //Persist Security Info=True";
            for(int i=0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
                {
                string StrQuery = "INSERT INTO script_Orders (" + "script, " + "cust_Name) VALUES (" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Prescription"].Value + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Customer_Name"].Value + ");";
                try
                    {
                        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection (ConnString))
                            {
                            using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(StrQuery, conn))
                                {
                                conn.Open();
                                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                conn.Close();
                                }
                            }
                    }
                catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Don't put SQL in your code-behind.

Comment: Use parameterized SQL rather than including the values directly. Your current approach makes it harder to diagnose errors like this *and* opens you up to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
string StrQuery = String.Format("INSERT INTO script_Orders(script,cust_Name) VALUES ('{0}','{1}')", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Prescription"].Value,  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Customer_Name"].Value);
```

Comment: this should work because it looks like he was missing the `'` surrounding the string values.

Comment: I should mention that the first column in my database is an auto-numbering column, should it then be:
`string StrQuery = String.Format("INSERT INTO script_Orders(script,cust_Name) VALUES ('{1}','{2}')", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Prescription"].Value,  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Customer_Name"].Value);`

Comment: No. The {0} and {1} are just orders of the parameters. Its nothing to do with your query. Please read about String.Format().